# Вывод сообщения исключения

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Хочу сделать обработку исключений в `debug` режиме в `Visual Studio 2015`:

```
try 
{
// ...
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    _ASSERT_EXPR(false, e.what()); 
}
```

Однако этот макрос принимает расширенные строки, поэтому получаю иероглифы вместо верного текста. Можно ли как-нибудь верно вывести текст сообщения без консоли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `_CrtDbgReport`, а не `_CrtDbgReportW`, которая использована в `_ASSERT_EXPR`.

```
_CrtDbgReport(_CRT_ERROR, __FILE__, __LINE__, NULL, "Exception: %s", e.what());
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало